# Heroku migration Memory quota exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, delayed-job, rails-migrations

While running a migration that looks like this:

```ruby
def up
  FileThumb.destroy_all # delete existing thumbnails
  File.update_all(thumbs_completed: false) # reset the process flags
  File.find_each do |file|
    file.delay(priority: 8).create_thumbs # delay thumbnail creation of each file.
  end
end
```

I'm getting Memory quote exceeded

```
heroku/run.8084:  source=run.8084 dyno=heroku.3498745.1deecee6-afd0-466a-8020-38273704608c sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.02 
heroku/run.8084:  source=run.8084 dyno=heroku.3498745.1deecee6-afd0-466a-8020-38273704608c sample#memory_total=571.66MB sample#memory_rss=511.89MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=59.78MB sample#memory_pgpgin=1811564pages sample#memory_pgpgout=1680521pages 
heroku/run.8084:  Process running mem=571M(111.7%) 
heroku/run.8084:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded  You are using more memory than the dyno has.  It should still be working as its an R14 error and not a R15.

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller batch size with `find_each`?

Comment: Although I wasn't getting R15 errors, it was hanging and stalled on insertions. A smaller batch size did work with find_in_batches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of so many objects are getting created in your migration you have to changed the query so less memory will be used.
Answer of your question is in this question :[Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded): How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875280/heroku-error-r14-memory-quota-exceeded-how-do-i-solve-this)

More specifically, the fix should be...

```ruby
def up
  FileThumb.destroy_all # delete existing thumbnails
  File.update_all(thumbs_completed: false) # reset the process flags
  File.find_in_batches(batch_size: 100) do |group|
    group.each {|file| file.delay(priority: 8).create_thumbs} # delay thumbnail creation of each file.
  end
end
```