# Sunspot:reindex causes R14 Memory exceeded error in heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, solr, sunspot, websolr

I am trying to reindex a couple mongo collections into WebSolr. Smaller collections get indexed just fine, but I cant get Sunspot to reindex the larger ones (~150k documents) without running out of memory. I've tried isolating the Models and adding batches of 10 and 5 with no luck.

I can index these on my local machine into a local instance of solr just fine.

Also, is there a way to migrate a local solr index to websolr?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code or knowing anything about the data, I can only guess at the problem, but it sounds like this is probably an issue with the way you're loading the data in Sunspot.

To clarify a bit, when you perform a reindex operation, Sunspot is reading from your primary data store (MongoDB in this case) and then sending that data to websolr. If you're using something like `Model.all`, then Sunspot is loading *all* of that model's data into memory. If you have a lot of records, then that could easily result in an R14 error, where Heroku complains that you're exceeding your memory quota. Further, the reason you don't have this problem locally is likely due to the amount of memory you have available on your local machine, compared to what you're getting on Heroku.

This also explains why batching didn't help. Batching in Sunspot means Sunspot will take the data it has loaded in memory and send it to Solr in batches; obviously if the memory footprint of that data is already over the quota set by Heroku, you'll still get the R14. Instead, you'll need to perform batching with ActiveRecord to keep memory usage down.

Take a look at using the `find_each` method, which loads the data into memory in batches rather than all at once. That is, replace `Model.all` with something like `Model.find_each(batch_size: <something>)`, where `<something>` is a batch size that is small enough to avoid the R14 error. Properly tuned, you should be able to reindex quickly without exceeding your memory quota in Heroku.

As far as your question about loading a local index to websolr, you could always use `heroku config` to find your `WEBSOLR_URL`. You could then configure your local Sunspot to point to this URL and run `rake sunspot:reindex`. That should migrate your data from the local environment to your websolr index.

Sources:

- [ActiveRecord batching docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)
- [Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded): How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875280/heroku-error-r14-memory-quota-exceeded-how-do-i-solve-this)