# How does one get a Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) at 524MB while running on 2x dyno with 1GB?

Tags: heroku

I have a 2x dyno with 1GB but Heroku gives me frequent R14 at roughly half that value.  I verified the 2x dyno with heroku ps.  Definitely getting charged for 2x dyno.  Should I be asking for a refund?  Feels like I do not really have a 2x dyno here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded): How do I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875280/heroku-error-r14-memory-quota-exceeded-how-do-i-solve-this)